# 64-bit replacement for [NSMenuItemCell menuView] and [NSMenuItemCell setMenuView]

Tags: macos, cocoa, 64-bit, menuitem, nsmenuitem

What are the 64-bit replacements for the two methods `-[NSMenuItemCell menuView]` and `-[NSMenuItemCell setMenuView:]` of the `NSMenuItemCell` class?
How can I obtain the same results?

Comment: What makes you think your app needs to be 64 bit ?

Comment: @Paul R: The app is a movie player and I had a noticeable reduction of CPU usage and increase of performance switching to 64bit

Comment: Fair enough - just checking - many people just seem to assume that 64 bits == "better" without any justification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NSMenuItemCell` and `NSMenuView` have never been used to draw menus in any release version of Mac OS X. The following is an excerpt from the Mac OS X Developer Release Notes:

> ### Notes specific to MacOS X Developer Preview 3
>
> **Menu**
>
> The implementation of menus has changed drastically; `NSMenuView` and
>   `NSMenuItemCell` are no longer used, `-[NSMenu menuRepresentation]` now
>   returns `nil`, and tear off menus are no longer available. For Developer
>   Preview 3, there is no support for menu item images. If there is no
>   text in the menu item, a placeholder text consisting of "< image >" or
>   "< image name >" will be inserted instead. Menu item state images are
>   not supported either and in their place the standard checkbox or dash
>   for on and mixed states are used.

(I'm not sure of the exact timeline of pre-Public beta Mac OS X, but for "Developer Preview 3", I'd guess we're talking around the late 1990s here).

For more info on how menus are currently implemented, see [Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics: How Menus Work](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/HowMenusWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000259-CJBGFCAA)

As 一二三 alluded to, you use `NSMenu` along with `NSMenuItem` to implement menus. In OS X 10.5 and greater, you can use custom `NSView` instances in `NSMenuItem`s using the `-setView:` method.

Comment: Mac OS X DP3 came out in January 2000, so you're pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

To customise menu item drawing, you need to supply a custom view to [`NSMenuItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/setView%3a).